# constant pointer to structure element in constant structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants

I am trying to access structure element via constant pointer. Program works like it should but I got warning 'intialization from incompatible pointer type' and '(near initalization for 'B.settings)'. I don't really know how to correctly initalize it. Can someone pls help me figure that out?

Here's my code :

It's just a snippet of larger part. Idea is to have access to  structure variables x,y when moving via pointers to const structure. Hope that make sense.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#define PGM_STR(X) ((const  char[]) { X })

struct SettingsStruct 
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;

}Settings;
   
struct constitem
{
 const char * const  text;
 const struct constitem *next;
 const struct  SettingsStruct  * settings;
};

struct constitem const  A;

struct constitem const  B = {PGM_STR("x"), &A, &Settings.x };
struct constitem const  A = {PGM_STR("y"), &B, &Settings.y };

static const struct constitem *currMenuPtr=&A; 

void main()
{
 Settings.x = 1;
 Settings.y = 2;

   printf("%s\n",currMenuPtr->text);
    printf("%d\n",*(currMenuPtr->settings));

    currMenuPtr = currMenuPtr->next;
   
   printf("%s\n",currMenuPtr->text);
   printf("%d\n",*(currMenuPtr->settings));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `Settings.x` is an `unsigned int`, and therefore `&Settings.x` is an `unsigned int *`.  You are trying to use it to initialize a value of type `const struct  SettingsStruct *`.  The compiler is quite right to complain -- what you are doing is highly questionable, and I suppose probably not what you actually mean to do.  The same applies to `Settings.y`.

It looks like you could get the compiler to stop complaining (about that) by changing the type of the third element of `struct constitem` to `unsigned int *`.  You'll have to judge whether that actually works for you in the larger scheme of your program, though.

There is also a problem with using `&A` in the initializer for variable `B` when `A` is not yet declared at the point where the initializer appears.  Inasmuch as you also refer to `B` in `A`'s initializer, you can't solve that by swapping the declaration order.  If you really do want a circular chain of pointers, then the pointer values cannot be `const`, because at least one of them will need to be modified after initialization.